# Como utilizar websocket em aplicativo hospedado da Aws Beanstalk

Tags: spring, amazon-aws, websocket, elastic-beanstalk

Tenho um sistema rodando na **aws beanstalk**, é um aplicativo Java com arquitetura **Tomcat + Spring**. Estou encontrando dificuldades para **fazer funcionar o websocket**, que localmente está funcional. O receptor do websocket atende para na url `dominio/socket`, e a conexão no cliente é feita em javascript da seguinte maneira:

```
new WebSocket("wss://dominio/socket");
```

Na aws o aplicativo roda no elastic beanstalk, com um **balanceador de carga de aplicativos**.Tentei de diversas maneiras fazer funcionar, contudo tenho o seguinte retorno:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Algumas informações sobre ambiente atual:

- As portas 80, 8080 e 443 estão abertas no load balancer;
- Criei um target groups, habilitei o Stickiness e associei ao load balancer no path `/socket` nos protocolos http e https;
- O https está configurado com certificado gerado pela aws;
- O balanceador de carga gerencia 2 instâncias.

Estou ficando sem alternativas, já pesquisei bastante e tentei reproduzir algumas idéias, contudo sem sucesso até o momento. Não sei se o fato de existir um balanceador de carga com duas instâncias invalida a arquitetura atual.

Peço alguma sugestão para a questão e/ou compartilhamento de utilização de websocket na aws com artquitetura similiar.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, vou adicionar a solução adotada pois pode ser útil a outras pessoas.

Partindo da arquitetura apresentada na questão, fiz os seguintes ajustes:

- Liberei a **porta 8080** no protocolo TCP (Type "Custom TCP Rule"). Para tanto adicionei uma regra no inbound e no outbound no **security group** associado ao load balancer em questão;
- Criei um **novo "target group"** associado à porta 8080 e nos atributos marquei a opção **"Stickiness"**;
- Associei o target group criado ao load balancer para interceptar requisições da **porta 8080 do path relacionado ao end point do websocket**.
- Alterei o código fonte para **especificar a porta de conexão** com websocket, por ex: `wss://[dominio]:8080/[end_point]`

Feito essa configuração a aplicação passou pertimir conexão via websocket com o load balancer application na aws.